# Running multiple system commands using Java

Tags: java, runtime

How can I run multiple windows system commands (using Java) in order, with the second depending on the result of the first?

Like this:

```
adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell
ls
```

and get the list result.

This is my source code, but it is not working:

```
public void connectToDevice(String device) {
    List<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
    cmd.add("adb.exe -s " + device + " shell");
    cmd.add("ls");
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ProcessBuilder(List<String>)` constructor is not intended to run multiple commands in parallel. it takes first element list as command and subsequent elements as its arguments so what is actually executed is `adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell ls` as one command. split this into two processes:

```
ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder("adb.exe -s " + device + " shell");
pb1.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p1 = pb1.start();
p1.waitFor();

ProcessBuilder pb2 = new ProcessBuilder("ls");
pb2.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p2 = pb2.start();
p2.waitFor();
```

Comment: java.lang.ProcessBuilder class doesn't have waitFor method - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html. Which class did you use in your example?

Comment: thank you mantrid, yes, ProcessBuilder  doesn't have waitFor method.
my object is get the folder list of my emulator, i have difficult to get it. because firstly i have to run the emulator, secondly get the list

Comment: ah indeed I forgot to invoke waitFor() on Process itself rather than builder